# all series on a given axis must be of the same data type .google chart api error

Tags: javascript, json, dom, javascript-objects, google-visualization

i am using google chart api in which i am fetching values from json .i am sharing my javascript with json here.its giving me error like it must be same data type but as for my knowledge it is of same type.

```
function drawChart2() {

  var jsa = [
    {
        "date": "01-APR-16",
        "creditCardCount": 3,
        "invoiceCount": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "06-APR-16",
        "creditCardCount": 2,
        "invoiceCount": 3
    },
    {
        "date": "29-MAR-16",
        "creditCardCount": 3,
        "invoiceCount": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "30-MAR-16",
        "creditCardCount": 4,
        "invoiceCount": 3
    },
    {
        "date": "31-MAR-16",
        "creditCardCount": 1,
        "invoiceCount": 1
    }
]


var outputArrayForInvoiceAndCredit = new Array();
// header
var headerArray1 = ['Day', 'CreditCard', 'Invoice'];
outputArrayForInvoiceAndCredit.push(headerArray1);
for (var i = 0; i < jsa.length; i++){
    var obj1 = jsa[i];
    var innerArray = new Array();
    innerArray[0] = obj1.date;
    innerArray[1] = obj1.creditCardCount;
    innerArray[2] = obj1.InvoiceCount;
    outputArrayForInvoiceAndCredit.push(innerArray);
}

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(outputArrayForInvoiceAndCredit);

  var options2 = {
    title: 'CreaditCard/Invoice Details',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('cc/invoice'));

  chart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
```

meanwhile if i use it without json it is working fine
below is the script which works fine

```html
  function drawChart3() {
  var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Day', 'Sales','exp'],
    ['4-APRIL-16', 1000,200],
    ['5-APRIL-16', 1170,300],
    ['6-APRIL-16', 660,400],
    ['7-APRIL-16', 1030,500]
  ]);

  var options3 = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  };

  var chart3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart3.draw(data3, options3);
}
```

can anyone help me into this.Thank you

Comment: not sure if related but note that you are doing `.InvoiceCount` instead of `.invoiceCount`

Comment: thanks man its working..smaller mistake but very difficult to find out :)

Comment: Has happened to me in the past and the blue color on .Invoice was helpful :)